# How can I set the y axis of the Trellis plot properly so it is not smudged?

Tags: python, spyder, plotly-python

I am trying to make a Trellis plot for the data set but I am unable to get it working. The plot works on Jupiter notebook with **fig.show()** with proper spaces. But somehow I need to set the renderer to see the graph in Spyder 4. I need to generate the plot in spyder 4 and save it afterwords. The saving part is easy though.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df, x='Shooter Race', y='Total Number of Fatalities',
             labels={
                 "Total Number of Victims": "Victims",
                 "Total Number of Fatalities": "Fatalities",
                 "Shooter Race":'Race',
             },
             width=None,

            facet_col='binned', facet_col_wrap=2)


fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1])) # removing the facet_col col name
fig.update_layout(
autosize=False,
width=800,
height=800,)

fig.show(renderer='png') # I need to save it in .png
```

**My output**

[image: plot output]

I tried the fig update parameters as follows **But still no luck**

```
    fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=800,
    height=800,)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Removing**
`fig.show(renderer='png')`

**and replacing with**

```
fig.show()
fig.write_image("fig1.png")
```

Somehow solves the issue. But I am not sure what is the logic behind this weird issue, i'd like to know about this thankyou.